# How to sort a data in a column based on specific sample name characters in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, character, analysis

I have a data frame (in R) that needs to be sorted out by parts of the sample name to do analysis. For example, each sample is coded in this format in a column titled "Sample":
1.4.a.2021
1 is the week
4 is the device number
a is the sampling period in the week
and 2021 is the year.
I want to sort by the "4" (numbers range from 1-12). Can I sort by a particular character in a string--if that is what this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your data is something like this:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Sample = paste0("1.", sample(12), ".",sample(letters, 12), "2021"),
                 Data = runif(12))
df
#>        Sample      Data
#> 1   1.9.u2021 0.3823880
#> 2   1.4.j2021 0.8696908
#> 3   1.7.v2021 0.3403490
#> 4   1.1.n2021 0.4820801
#> 5   1.2.y2021 0.5995658
#> 6   1.5.g2021 0.4935413
#> 7   1.3.i2021 0.1862176
#> 8   1.8.o2021 0.8273733
#> 9   1.6.e2021 0.6684667
#> 10 1.11.t2021 0.7942399
#> 11 1.12.q2021 0.1079436
#> 12 1.10.w2021 0.7237109
```

To sort it we can find the number portion of the string, convert to numeric and order the data frame by it:

```
df[order(as.numeric(gsub("^.*\\.(\\d+)\\..*$", "\\1", df$Sample))),]
#>        Sample      Data
#> 4   1.1.n2021 0.4820801
#> 5   1.2.y2021 0.5995658
#> 7   1.3.i2021 0.1862176
#> 2   1.4.j2021 0.8696908
#> 6   1.5.g2021 0.4935413
#> 9   1.6.e2021 0.6684667
#> 3   1.7.v2021 0.3403490
#> 8   1.8.o2021 0.8273733
#> 1   1.9.u2021 0.3823880
#> 12 1.10.w2021 0.7237109
#> 10 1.11.t2021 0.7942399
#> 11 1.12.q2021 0.1079436
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Here's a different approach that might be useful if you wanted to extract other components from `Sample`, `as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Sample, "\\."), "[", 2))`.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to work with what you used currently! Could you possibly explain the breakdown of the gsub() with the parameters in ""? I also have a set with 1.4.a.2021 where I removed the data in the file, so I am trying to modify based on that.

Comment: The regex inside gsub means "from the start of the string `^` read and ignore all the characters `.*` until you come to a period `\\.`, then capture one or more digits `(\\d)` until you come to a period `\\.` . Following that, ignore all other characters `.*` until the end of the string `$`. The second argument to gsub `\\1` means replace the matched string with the first capturing group (there was only one capturing group here, with the numbers we wanted).

Comment: @AllanCameron sorry to bug you again--- after moving through my data, I now need to sort the same string using the first character in the string (I am grouping by week and device number now). I tried to follow your regex and sort through it but I am failing (consistently). If I was to sort by the "1" in the " 1.4.a.2021" --how do I alter the regex? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hopefully just `"^(\\d+)\\..*$"` @LexiHeger